# Mass method invocation

Tags: ruby

So in Ruby one can mass assign variables like this:

```
a, b, c = [1, 2, 3]
```

But what if I wanted to do the same for object methods, but without having to write out the whole thing like so:

```
foo.a, foo.b, foo.c = [1, 2, 3]
```

Is there a DRY way to accomplish this?

Comment: "the whole thing" is __shorter__ than this (even including newlines!), so I don't really see what would be the benefit of this.

Comment: in the Ruby, `foo.c = 1` it's not assignment. it is  a method invocation

Comment: Why the downvote? Just checking if it exists.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Well if the name is longer than `foo` and you have a few more it's not DRY.

Comment: If you are in frequent need of such situation, then it is indication that you should rather keep them together as a single attribute.

Comment: @dan-klasson: you're taking the idea of DRY to absurd levels. I wouldn't worry about it here. Literally the only thing you're repeating here is `foo`. So what? Later on you need to rename `foo`? Use "rename" refactoring of your editor. It is also very easy to manually replace variable name in several consecutive lines.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: I was just checking if it existed. Would be nice to go with a one-liner, but since that's not possible I won't. But at least now I know. Don't understand why people would downvote for being curios.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure you’ll like it, but the DRYest way I can think of is:

```
[:a, :b, :c].zip([1, 2, 3]).each { |k, v| foo.public_send "#{k}=", v }
# or vice versa
[1, 2, 3].zip([:a, :b, :c]).each { |v, k| foo.public_send "#{k}=", v }
```

Or, in more OO way:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :a, :b, :c
  def massive_assign attrs, values
    attrs.zip(values).each { |k, v| public_send "#{k}=", v }
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.massive_assign([:a, :b, :c], [1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking too. I guess explicit is better than implicit applies here.

Comment: What do you mean? That still repeats `foo` three times.

Comment: This is, IMHO, the sort of "DRY" that you *don't* want to do. This code has a very high "wtf is this?" rating. Just type the assignments. It's clear. It's obvious. It's readable. No need to abstract it away with a class.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Yes, I kinda agree, but it depends. When one is to choose between, say, json builder and this `massive_assign` I would go with the latter.

Comment: @mudasobwa Using a hash and a loop seems a lot better to me. That's a lot more readable and easier to modify. If you have 50 keys, and you want to modify key 27 (or want to add one at position 27), then how are you going to do that with this code? Both examples make that very awkward since you need to find the right location twice and it's very easy to miscount. If you *must* use an array for whatever reason, then I would do it as `[[:a, 1], [:b, 2], ...]` Ironical, this is what your `zip` in the first example actually produces! I don't understand why you wrote it that way?

Comment: I wrote it that way to make it as close as possible to OP, which had `[1, 2, 3]` on the right hand.

Comment: Okay, fair enough ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Mass assignment to instance variables can be done like below as well:

```
foo.instance_eval { @a, @b, @c = [1, 2, 3] }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no specific syntax, but you could implement a setter for multiple attributes that are passed as a *hash*. Rails uses a similar approach:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :a, :b, :c

  def attributes=(attrs)
    attrs.each do |name, value|
      public_send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
#=> #<Foo:0x007fc6d8a1e950>

foo.attributes = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
#=> #<Foo:0x007fc6d8a1e950 @a=1, @b=2, @c=3>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the comments up there I assume that the poster is meaning a case where it's not actually `foo` but a more complex expression; and not only 3 assignments (method calls) but many.

There are 2 techniques that come to mind: `tap` and `send`:

```
some.complex[expression].which.evaluates.to.the.receiving.object.tap do |obj|
  value_hash.each_pair do |key,value|
    obj.send("#{key}=", value)
  end
end
```

Hope that helps.

Of course, the usual security caveats apply (better make sure `value_hash` only contains valid/sane/allowed names).